# SQL Server 2005 - ALTER TABLE AFTER COLUMN

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

There is any way to include one or more columns in a specific order (after X column, for eg) in SQL Server 2005? Or something like change the master, or a sysobject, or a MODIFY command?

**Please:**

**NOT MySQL** (`AFTER COLUMN` doesn't work)

**NOT DROP TABLE-CREATE TABLE** (I can NOT implement this option on production without put down the application)

**I can NOT touch the application**, it's not my APP or APP.Team

**I can NOT KNOW** if there is somewhere in the application there is a **SELECT * FROM** so **I must assume that YES, there is.**

**No, is not a desire, is an specific requirement**, the table gets a **feed from external source** (app) through a job.

Comment: The order of columns in a relational table is irrelevant - it has no impact on functionality - it's purely a "cosmetic" thing. Thus, SQL Server does **NOT** have any T-SQL commands to re-order the columns. The **only way** to do this in SQL Server would be to re-create the table with the columns listed in the order you want.

Comment: You can of course create a View with your desired column order. Why does it matter? Is it you just want to see related columns together?

Comment: Ugh. I hate looking at a bunch of tables in Management Studio that have dozens of columns in no particular order.

Comment: please review the post, I edited it.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need this? If you have an App not in your control that does `select * ...` and depends on column positions you will most certainly break something if you insert a column somewhere in the middle. It would be safer to add the column at the end.

Comment: Yes, sure. The insert of the table (the feed) comes in that format, but the select (output) is required from the external app. If i do not put exactly the order, i crash the feed. If there is a select * from, it will crash only on reports. I trying to raise the better issue.

Comment: @Leandro - Well you can rename the table and create a view with the original table name.

Comment: Thanks Martin Smith, its the better answer until now. Please write it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only add columns at the end.

And even that will use a schema modify lock for a short time, so in a very sensitive production environment, you should be aware of this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Comment: And also will lead to performance issues due to page splits and/or pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, anyway I need to find another work around

Comment: @Leandro Without knowing why you need new columns inserted in a certain order and when, I can't help further.  This is one reason it is dangerous to give applications/users table-level access.  By giving apps/users stored procedure and view access only, the underlying table structure is abstracted and refactoring is more easily facilitated.

Answer (score 1):

If your app depends on a specific order of columns, the cure is not to change the column order, but to fix the app.

Some of the principles of RDBMS operation are better understood than others, and every definition of 1NF I know of concurs, that column order is to be considered without meaning.

Comment: I know, but I can not do this directly, it's not my app